# Intellij Projects

Tags: java, intellij-idea, project

So I accidentally made my Documents folder into a project folder in Intellij and every time I open Intellij my entire Document folder opens up as a project. How can I get rid of this issue. Also, every time I open Intellij it opens up to a the previous project I was working on. How can I configure it to open up into a blank file?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Idea to show "Hello page" on startup in next way:
`Intellij Idea - Preferences - Appearance and behavior - System settings` and uncheck "Reopen last project on startup"

As for Documents directory - just create another project wherever you want through `File - New - Project`